# How to use AndroidViewClient findViewWithText() with regex

Tags: android, python, regex, androidviewclient

I have a script to monitor the Notifications screen page.

I can open it via "Culebra" option "UiDevice" -> "Open Notifications".
The notifications error message from some apps have starting characters which are changing, only a constant pattern like "error for" is common but located at different position of the `TextView` error messages.

Therefore I can't use a regex with the method `findViewWithText(regex)` as it seems to use a regex `match()` instead of regex `search()`. Another solution for my problem is to use `traverse()` method with my own transform method which can do a regex `search()` of the view attribute text, but I can't figure out how to pass a parameter like a regex to my own transform method!?

Comment: add some code, if you want us to help. There is no way someone could help you with only a wall of text as information.

Comment: sure, solution 1:  
`t = re.compile('error for')`  
`error_id = vc.findViewWithTextOrRaise(t)`

Comment: solution 2, of course this code does not work and I need to lear how to format code here too :)  
`def findViewWithSearch(view, regex):  
    # Return the view if text property of the view contains the regex  
    if view.getClass() == 'android.widget.TextView':  
        search_obj = regex.search(view.text())  
        if search_obj:  
            logger.info("text: %s", view.getText())  
regex = re.compile("error for")  
vc.traverse(transform=findViewWithSearch(regex))`

Comment: edit your initial question and add this code. other viewer won't read the comments and just move on to the next question.

Comment: I understand, but I would like to avoid to post wrong codes in the question because those 2 solutions do not work for my case. The simple solution is just to replace the regex match by search of the line code "if root and attr in root.map and regex.match(root.map[attr]):" in the method __findViewWithAttributeInTreeThatMatches() of viewclient.py. But surely it needs first to be discussed with the owner of AndroidViewClient :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me to touch on a notification with text **USB debugging connected**:

```
vc.findViewWithTextOrRaise(re.compile('.*USB.*'), root=vc.findViewByIdOrRaise('id/no_id/3')).touch()
vc.sleep(_s)
```

notice this is a modified `culebra` script, that's why `findViewWithTextOrRaise()` is using the `root` argument to limit the search to the subtree which may not be needed in all cases, but it's safer to use.

It's worth to mention, that this works too

```
vc.findViewWithTextOrRaise(re.compile('.*debugging.*'), root=vc.findViewByIdOrRaise('id/no_id/3')).touch()
```

Comment: your example is working perfectly, now I see my mistake, my bad, I forget to add '.*' in my regex, so my regex '.*error for.*' is working fine, I need to re-study regexp :) , thank you very much!!!